# Jinja2 include & extends not working as expected

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I used `include` and `extends` in the `base.html` file and expect them to be included in order. But the `extends` template is appended to the end of the file.

I expect my template to give me the output of:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Test String from block !</p>
<footer>text from footer.</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

but the current result are:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<footer>text from footer.</footer>
</body>
</html>
       <p>Test String from block !</p>
```

In `base.html`, first I include `header.html`, then `content.html` and then `footer.html` but the rendered order is `header.html`, `footer.html`, `content.html`.

`index.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <p>Test String from block !</p>
{% endblock %}
```

`base.html`

```
{% include "header.html" %}
<body>
    {% extends "content.html" %}
{% include "footer.html" %}
```

`header.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
```

`content.html`

```
{% block content %}

{% endblock %}
```

`footer.html`

```
<footer>text from footer.</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest structuring slightly differently.  I used a structure like this just recently and got the proper results.

index.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block head %}
    <!-- if you want to change the <head> somehow, you can do that here -->
{% endblock head %}

{% block content %}
<body>
    <p>Test String from block !</p>
    {% include 'content.html' %}
</body>
{% include 'footer.html' %}
{% endblock content %}
```

base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        {% block head %}
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        {% endblock head %}
    </head>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}
</html>
```

content.html:

```
<!-- whatever you want in here -->
```

footer.html:

```
<footer>text from footer.</footer>
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Why that thing happened before?is that a bug of flask/jinja or it was my bad?

Comment: I think it was a matter of the order the files were pulling each other in somehow, but I can't really say for sure.

Comment: Your answer works great.i will also make a issue on `jinja` github repository.thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to use `include` instead of `extends` in

```
{% extends "content.html" %}
```